# Header 100% Width inside wrapper

Tags: html, css

so based of my structure I'm using, the header section is inside a wrap div. This wrap div has a set width

```
width: 1000px;
```

but **I want my header to go past this 1000px width, I would like the header to be the entire width of the browser!**

You can see the code in my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7eLnegvd/
You might need to expand the width of the preview section so you can see the header doesn't fill 100% width.

Thanks!

Comment: Take it out of the wrapper...it's not hard.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you change your way?
dont place you header tag in your wrapper div. use Semantic tags like header tag, main tag, footer tag and... outside div wrapper and style header tag separate LIKE A BOSS!

HTML:

```
<body>

<header>header</header>
<div class="wrapper">body</div>
<footer>footer</footer>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
}

header,
footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper{
    width: 1024px;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `width: 1000px;` and by default the wrapper will be a block element which is the entire width of the page

Answer (score 0):

If you want the width attribute of an element to be a maximum width you can use percentage instead of pixels. you can also add additional width attributes to your code and set the minimum or the maximum width that you want.

CSS example:

```
#wrap {
min-width: 5em;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

In addition, It's recommended to use [CSS3 @media Rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) for such type of design to make it more responsive.